# Why doesn't my Perl one-liner work on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl

From the Windows command prompt I generate a text file of all the files in a directory:

```
dir c:\logfiles /B > config.txt
```

Output:

```
0001_832ec657.log
0002_a7c8eafc.log
```

I need to feed the "config.txt" file to another executable, but before I do so, I need to modify the file to add some additional information that the executable needs. So I use the following command:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's/log/log,XYZ/g' config.txt
```

I'm expecting the result to be:

```
0001_832ec657.log,XYZ
0002_a7c8eafc.log,XYZ
```

However, the "config.txt" file is not modified. Using the "-w" option, I get the warning message:

> Useless use of a constant in void context at -e line 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This could be the canonical question for how to run Perl one-liners on Windows.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Windows `cmd.exe` does not use `'` as string delimiters, only `"`.  What you're doing is equivalent to:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e "'s/log/log,XYZ/g'" config.txt
```

so `-w` is complaining "you gave me a string but it does nothing".

The solution is to use double quotes instead:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e "s/log/log,XYZ/g" config.txt
```

or to simply leave them off, since there's no metacharacters in this command that would be interpreted by `cmd.exe`.

#### Addendum

`cmd.exe` is just a really troublesome beast, for anybody accustomed to `sh`-like shells.  Here's a few other common failures and workarounds regarding `perl` invocation.

```
@REM doesn't work:
perl -e"print"
@REM works:
perl -e "print"
@REM doesn't work:
perl -e "print \"Hello, world!\n\""
@REM works:
perl -e "print qq(Hello, world!\n)"
```

Comment: @ephemient Thanks for this addendum. Very usefull. In my case `perl -e "print \"Hello, world!\n\""` seems to work.

Answer (score 6):

[ephemient](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20713/ephemient)'s answer summarizes the problem well, but you do have another option: change your shell from `cmd.exe` to a better shell. If you are a Unix type person then I would suggest looking into [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) which provides the sort of environment you are used to (for example, [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) and GNU utilities).

If you are a Windows-type person I would suggest looking at [PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx) (née MSH née Monad). In fact, I would suggest looking into PowerShell even if you are Unix type person. It integrates with [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) and has many neat features (like objects being passed through pipes rather than simple lines of text). If I were stuck on a Microsoft OS, it is the shell I would be using.

Other shells for Windows that people seem to like:

- [UWIN](http://www.research.att.com/sw/tools/uwin/)
- [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)
- [UnixUtils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils)
- [Microsoft Windows Services for UNIX (SFU)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_Services_for_UNIX)
- [MKS Toolkit](http://www.mkssoftware.com/products/)

Comment: Yeah, or just use double quotes.  What if this code has to run on other machines?  There is nothing he which would require replacing cmd.

Comment: One liners are not meant to be portable code.  And how likely is it that Perl will be installed on another Windows machine? Also, if you are a Windows person it is probably a good idea to get used to PowerShell since it is part of 2008 Server.

Comment: Cmd.exe sucks badly, if it gets in your way enough a shell change is worth considering.  Another shell is worth considering.  MSYS and MinGW provide a lighter weight way to get your unix environment than Cygwin.  They, too, are worth looking into.  http://www.mingw.org/