# Why doesn't Perl see my file in the working Windows directory?

Tags: perl

I'm using the current release of Strawberry Perl and Windows Server 2008.

For some reason Perl doesn't seem to find files in the current working directory:

```
F:\temp\hackr\e>ls
test.csv      train.csv

F:\temp\hackr\e>perl -ne 'print if (rand() < .01)' train.csv
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Are you sure it finds `perl`?

Comment: @simbabque  Good question. When I just type `perl` and enter there's no error. It drops down a line waiting for further commands. So I think it finds perl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the Windows command line, use double quotes around command line arguments that need quoting.

```
perl -ne "print if (rand() < .01)" train.csv
```

Comment: @Hack-R:  Linux will accept either double or single quotes on the command line (with different behaviours) but Windows insists on double-quotes