# Comment XML lines beginning with specific string using perl -p -ie

Tags: xml, perl, replace, comments

How can I search for lines beginning with a certain string in an XML file and comment them using **perl -pi -e 's/string/replacement/g' /path/file**? I know how to use it for basic text replacement but I don't know how to do this.

Specifically, i want to comment out the all shadow lines:

```
<button function="close" state="prelight" draw_ops="close_focused_prelight"/>
<button function="close" state="pressed" draw_ops="close_focused_pressed"/>
<shadow radius="8.0" opacity="0.75" color="#abde4f" x_offset="1" y_offset="4"/>
<padding left="7" right="7" bottom="7"/>
```

to

```
<button function="close" state="prelight" draw_ops="close_focused_prelight"/>
<button function="close" state="pressed" draw_ops="close_focused_pressed"/>
<!--    <shadow radius="8.0" opacity="0.75" color="#abde4f" x_offset="1" y_offset="4"/> -->
<padding left="7" right="7" bottom="7"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s/(<shadow .*?\/>)/<!-- $1 -->/
```

The ? indicates a non-greedy match to capture any characters up until '/>', which should match a shadow element even if it is not the only element on a line.

I forgot that you were doing this on the command line. I just validated this with your test input.

```
perl -pi -e "s/(<shadow .*?\/>)/<\!-- \$1 -->/" /tmp/t
```

Comment: **perl -pi -e 's/^(<shadow .*?/>)/<!-- $1 -->/g' theme.xml** returned "Unmatched ( in regex" so i escaped the / to **perl -pi -e 's/^(<shadow .*?\/>)/<!-- $1 -->/g' theme.xml** - still no changes

Comment: I just saw the link to your file above.  Your shadow lines have spaces at the beginning of the line.  So, the ^ beginning of line caret needs to be removed.  I update my solution.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. **perl -pi -e 's/(<shadow .*?\/>)/<!-- $1 -->/g' theme.xml** works perfectly. I just noticed your remark about the command line, does that mean I will need to modify the command for *nix shell scripts?

Comment: No it will execute fine in a shell script. I originally assumed this was a within a perl script. On the command line or a shell script the ! and $ both had to be escaped because they have their own meanings to the shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
s/^(<shadow .*)/<!-- $1 -->/mg;
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either, sorry I'm very new to perl. i tried perl -pi -e 's/^(<shadow .*)/<!-- $1 -->/mg;' theme.xml. The modification date changes but the file is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Perl oneliner has slight difference in usage among terminals
Read this for more information [Why doesn't my Perl one-liner work on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660624/why-doesnt-my-perl-one-liner-work-on-windows)

People will assume you are working on linux/unix by default if you dont specify the OS.

For windows use `perl -pi.bak -e "s/(^<shadow .*>)/<!-- $1 -->/" theme.xml`

For linux `perl -pi -e 's/(^<shadow .*>)/<!-- $1 -->/' theme.xml`

Comment: I'm on linux, but i still can't get this to work. File is here if you wish to test --> https://dl.dropbox.com/s/sralfi7hroio2nx/theme.xml