# Perl one-liner in Windows

Tags: regex, windows, perl, command-line

I have a [Perl one-liner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-liner_program#Perl) which will read a file and remove the first field of each line, which are separated by comma and dump the rest.

```
perl -wan -e 'for (@F) { if (/(aaa),(.*)/) {$text = $2; $text =~ s/$1// ; print "$text\n";}}'
```

Where aaa is in the first field of each line. This is working fine in Linux, but in Windows it is throwing an error:

> Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.`

Why is it behaving differently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Why doesn't my Perl one-liner work on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660624/why-doesnt-my-perl-one-liner-work-on-windows)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use double instead of single quotes. This might impose problems for quoted text `"$text\n"` which can be replaced by perl alternative quoting `qq{$text\n}`

```
perl -wane "for (@F) { if (/(aaa),(.*)/) {$text = $2; $text =~ s/$1//; print qq{$text\n}; }}"
```

Comment: Obviously perl has many ways to do things. But in a perl programme, if I am using "$text", its working fine, but not in the oneliner. Is there any specific reason ??

Comment: @PDK yes, double qoutes are used to enclose perl script, so it can not be used inside script unless backslashed. http://stackoverflow.com/a/660720/223226

Answer (score 2):

In MS Windows, single quotes don't work as in Linux. You have to switch to double quotes.

```
perl -wan -e "for (@F) { if (/(aaa),(.*)/) {$text = $2; $text =~ s/$1// ; print qq($text\n);}}"
```

I used `qq` for the nested double quotes.