# Unexpected character when running one-liner on Windows

Tags: perl, frequency-distribution

I want to generate an output file that shows the frequency of each word inside an input file. After some search, I found that Perl is the ideal language for this problem, but I don't know this language.

After some more search, I found the following code here at stackoverflow, supposedly it provides the solution I want at great efficiency:

```perl
perl -lane '$h{$_}++ for @F; END{for $w (sort {$h{$b}<=>$h{$a} || $a cmp $b} keys %h) {print "$h{$w}\t$w"}}' file > freq
```

I tried running this command line using the form below:

```
perl -lane 'code' input.txt > output.txt
```

The execution halts due to an unexpected '>' (the one at '<=>'). I did some research but can't understand what is wrong.
Could some one enlight me? Thanks!

Here is the topic from where I got the code:
[Elegant ways to count the frequency of words in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888879/elegant-ways-to-count-the-frequency-of-words-in-a-file)

If it's relevant, my words use letters and numbers and are separated by a single white space.

Comment: You might want to check out this article on Perl Maven, explaining how to write a script to produce word frequencies.  https://perlmaven.com/count-words-in-text-using-perl

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Why doesn't my Perl one-liner work on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660624/why-doesnt-my-perl-one-liner-work-on-windows)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably using Windows. You therefore need to use doubles quotes `"` instead of singles quotes `'` around your code:

```
perl -lane "$h{$_}++ for @F; END{for $w (sort {$h{$b}<=>$h{$a} || $a cmp $b} keys %h) {print qq($h{$w}\t$w)}}" file > freq
```

Also, note how I used `qq()` instead of `"..."` within the code, as suggested by @mob. Another option is to escape the quotes with `\"`.

Comment: Will escaping the quotes work? If not, the `qq{}` syntax offers a workaround  (`print qq[$h{$w}\t$w]`) .

Comment: @mob, I tried it on a Windows and it worked, but I'm not sure it works in every situation though. Gonna edit your `qq{}` suggestion in ;)